# Triggering fancybox from a link on page - Image gallery with multiple albums

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, fancybox, image-gallery

I made an image gallery with multiple albums each album containing different number of photos. I am trying to get two fancybox behavior

Req 1 - Clicking on the primary image of the album opens up a fancy box and navigates through the primary images of all albums. I got this part working

Req 2 - Beneath every album I have an anchor tag which displays the count of photos in the album. When I click on this anchor tag, fancy box should navigate through the photos of that particular album only.  I am not sure how to bind this anchor tag to the trigger fancybox and navigate through the images in the album. I have a static json file and i have two attributes `primaryPhoto` and `imagesContained(array)`.

Could someone please help me with how to get through this?

```
$.each(data.gallery,function(i,item) {
 $.each(item.albums, function(i,photos) {
        imageFolder = sec.mediumUrl;
        imgInsert += '<a href="' + photos + '" class="grouped_elements" rel="Gallery' + count + '" class="big_img"'  +'">';
    });
    '<a href="' + imgThumb + '" class="description2" title="Hello world">' + count + '</a></div>'; 
    count++;
});
```

I am trying to access it like this

```
$("a.description2").click(function() {
 $("a.grouped_elements").fancybox({
                'transitionIn': 'none',
                'transitionOut': 'none',
                'titlePosition': 'over',
                'titleFormat': function (title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
                    return '<span id="fancybox-title-over">Image ' + (currentIndex + 1) + ' / ' + currentArray.length + (title.length ? ' &nbsp; ' + title : '') + '</span>';
                }
            });

});
```

Comment: I guess you need to post some of your code here to get help faster.

Comment: @JFK Hi JFK added my partial code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**For Your Request 2**

I have been working on this issue for my own project all day, I just came up with a solution.

Say this is a gallery on your page:

```
<a id="Gallery_1" rel="gallery1" href="image_big_1.jpg"><img src="image_small_1.jpg" alt=""/></a>
<a rel="gallery1" href="image_big_2.jpg"><img src="image_small_2.jpg" alt=""/></a>
```

*Notice I have added an ID called "Gallery_1" to the first link in gallery 1*

Then, for the text you have below the gallery, use the following javascript:

```
<a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick='$("a#Gallery_1").trigger ("click");'>Your Link Text</a>
```

This worked perfectly for me. Hope it helps!

Comment: I'm sorry...not sure why it wouldn't work. I have it working on this site if you want to look at more code: http://tallycm.com/clients. Click the "+" buttons to activate the gallery the way you're trying to.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your html rendered code should be something like that:

Album 1:

```
<a class="grouped_elements" rel="gallery1" href="image01.jpg" title="title01"><img src="thumb01.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a class="grouped_elements" rel="gallery1" href="image02.jpg" title="title02"><img src="thumb02.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a class="grouped_elements" rel="gallery1" href="image03.jpg" title="title03"><img src="thumb03.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

etc.

Album 2:

```
<a class="grouped_elements" rel="gallery2" href="image10.jpg" title="title10"><img src="thumb10.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a class="grouped_elements" rel="gallery2" href="image11.jpg" title="title11"><img src="thumb11.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a class="grouped_elements" rel="gallery2" href="image12.jpg" title="title12"><img src="thumb12.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

etc.

Album 3:

```
<a class="grouped_elements" rel="gallery3" href="image20.jpg" title="title20"><img src="thumb20.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a class="grouped_elements" rel="gallery3" href="image21.jpg" title="title21"><img src="thumb21.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a class="grouped_elements" rel="gallery3" href="image22.jpg" title="title22"><img src="thumb21.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

etc.

**Notice** that each album has been set with a different `rel` attribute regardless that all of them share the same `class` so we can use `$("a.grouped_elements").fancybox({// options here})` to fire fancybox for any album.

Now, in order to launch each album from a different link (an anchor tag which displays the count of photos in the album as in your example), we will set an anchor for each album sharing the same `class` but with a different `ID` (@RevCocnept suggestion wasn't a bad idea.)

```
<a id="gallery1" class="description2" href="javascript:;">open album 1</a>
<a id="gallery2" class="description2" href="javascript:;">open album 2</a>
<a id="gallery3" class="description2" href="javascript:;">open album 3</a>
```

**Notice** that each `ID` has exactly the same value as the `rel` value of the corresponding album.

Now we can use a single script for those three anchors, targeting their shared `class` :

```
$(".description2").click(function(){
 $('.grouped_elements[rel="'+this.id+'"]').eq(0).trigger("click");
});
```

Notice that we used `.eq(0)` to start the gallery from the first element, otherwise it would start from the last element added in the DOM